# Step by step (show-your-work) example on how to solve a log problem algebraically

Tags: calculus, logarithms

It's been a long time since I have done calculus so if someone could please refresh my memory on the steps to solve the following problem algebraically that would be most appreciated. I am interested the step-by-step process of solving the problem algebraically without a calculator (if applicable), rather than just an answer (which is $n \approx 43.411$). The problem is as follows; solve for $n$:
$$n \leq 8 \log n$$
Thanks in advance

Comment: What base is the logarithm? Also, do you mean $n\le 8\log{n}$?

Comment: In general you can't solve equations by hand that involve $n$ both inside and outside a transcendental function like $\log$, unless there are numerical coincidences.

Comment: If a calculator is better to use that is fine, however I am still not sure how to arrive at the given answer. I am not sure what the base is, which is why I provided the answer so the base could (going out on a limb here) be derived that way. However, I can say that I am using the math to compare running times of two computer algorithms if that provides any reference frame. Here is a link the my previous question on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397284/for-inputs-of-size-n-for-which-values-of-n-does-insertion-sort-beat-merge-sort

Comment: It is not true : $43.11 > 8*\log(43.11) = 30.11$ (if $\log$ is the natural logarithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kind of problems usually need the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function, see the examples section. 
To get a solution near your $\approx 43.411,\;$ I guess the base of the logarithm is 2. Actually there are two solution for $n=8\log_2(n):$ 
$$n = \frac{-8}{\ln 2} W\Big(\frac{-8}{\ln 2}\Big) \approx 1.099997$$
or 
$$n = \frac{-8}{\ln 2}W_{-1}\Big(\frac{-8}{\ln 2}\Big) \approx 43.559260$$

If you do not want to use the Lambert W function, you can simply iterate the
formula $n = 8 \log_2(n),\;$ using a starting value $n_0.\;$ Here are two iterations with $n_0=20, \quad n_0=40: $

```
n = 40.0
n = 8*log[2](n)  n = 42.57542476
n = 8*log[2](n)  n = 43.29559214
n = 8*log[2](n)  n = 43.48918599
n = 8*log[2](n)  n = 43.54067840
n = 8*log[2](n)  n = 43.55433585

n = 20.0
n = 8*log[2](n)  n = 34.57542476
n = 8*log[2](n)  n = 40.89340056
n = 8*log[2](n)  n = 42.83036906
n = 8*log[2](n)  n = 43.36449763
n = 8*log[2](n)  n = 43.50753993
n = 8*log[2](n)  n = 43.54554831
```

Comment: How can there be two answers for the same problem? Sounds like quantum physics (lol).

Comment: This is a non-linear equation, and there can be more than one solution, remember quadratic equations?

Comment: The equation above looks pretty straight forward, however how does one calculate the W portion of the equation? Also is the (-1) in the second equation have something to do with an anti-derivative? How do I know which one I should use for a given calculation?

Comment: No, the Lambert W function is a complex multi-valued (multi-branched) function $W(k,x)$ where
k is the branch. In this case there are real solutions for $k=-1$ and $k=0,\;$
where zero is usually supressed.
For some more info see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

Comment: Thank you for your effort here!

Answer (score 0):

May be, you could consider the function $$f(x)=x-a \log_b(x)=x-\frac{a \log (x)}{\log (b)}$$ for which $$f'(x)=1-\frac{a}{x \log (b)}$$ $$f''(x)=\frac{a}{x^2 \log (b)}$$ The derivative cancels for $x_*=\frac{a}{\log (b)}$ and $$f(x_*)=\frac{a-a \log \left(\frac{a}{\log (b)}\right)}{\log (b)}$$ $$f''(x_*)=\frac{\log (b)}{a}$$ So, if $f(x_*)<0$ and $f''(x_*)>0$ as in the present case, two roots have to be and they are expressed in terms of Lambert function as gammatester answered.

Comment: @NateNeuhaus. You are very welcome !